# Enviar correo con phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tengo el siguiente código en phpmailer pero al enviar el correo me lanza el siguiente error

> ```
> "Call to undefined method PHPMailer::body()"
> ```

la versión de phpmailer que uso es 5.2.4

```
<?php

require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('phpmailer/class.smtp.php');


$mail = new PHPMailer(); 

$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';


$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->Username   = "micorreo";

$mail->Password   = "micorreo";

$email_to = "correo";
$email_subject = $_POST['asunto'];
$email_copy = $_POST['email'];
$body = $_POST['comments'];
$name = $_POST['nombre'];

$mail->SetFrom($email_copy, $name);


$mail->AddReplyTo($email_copy,$name);

$mail->AddAddress($email_to, 'nombre');  

$mail->Subject = $email_subject;

$mail->IsHTML(false);
$mail->body($body);


if(!$mail­>Send()) {
echo "Error al enviar el mensaje: " . $mail­>ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Mensaje enviado!!";
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Tienes la última versión estable, la 5.2.22? **No existe versión 5.2.4**  https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/releases Tus dos `require_once...` al principio me parecen extraños. Cuidado si no tienes bien instalado PHPMailer. ¿Por qué no lo usas como recomiendan sus creadores?: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer  Si lo tienes bien instalado no deberías tener problemas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes definir el cuerpo del mensaje usando `Body` con B mayúscula inicial. Por ejemplo:

```
 $mail->Body = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.";
```

(Ejemplo tomado de http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=tutorial)

Otra opción es usar el método `MsgHTML()`, que permite definir el mensaje usando formato HTML. Por ejemplo:

```
$mail->MsgHTML("<p>Enviando mensaje <b>con formato HTML</b>.</p>");
```

Comment: ya había intentado usando "Body" y me arroja el mismo error.

Answer (score 0):

Has probado modificar tambien `IsHTML(false);`, y ponerlo en `true`.

**Ejemplo:**

```
//Envio de correo electronico mediante HTML o texto plano.
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = $email_subject;
$mail->Body = "<i>Cuerpo mediante HTML.</i>";
$mail->AltBody = "Cuerpo mediante texto plano.";
```